# What is the bottleneck of loopback?

Tags: networking, macos, performance, loopback, iperf

Recently I am curious about that question, so I installed iperf3 on my macOS to benchmark my the performance of the loopback on my macOS. However, the CPU usages didn't reach 100%, which is expected because [some say the bottleneck of loopback should be CPU](https://serverfault.com/a/234318/355798). Am I missing something here? Thx.[image]

```
➜  Downloads iperf3 -c 127.0.0.1 -t 100
Connecting to host 127.0.0.1, port 5201
[  5] local 127.0.0.1 port 56269 connected to 127.0.0.1 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  6.13 GBytes  52.6 Gbits/sec
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  6.13 GBytes  52.7 Gbits/sec
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  6.13 GBytes  52.7 Gbits/sec
```